# Erro comparando strings em Delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou usando o código:

```
conexao.First;
while not conexao.Eof do
  begin
  if (conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02' and conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04') then
    total24:= total24 + conexao.FieldValues['val_tot'];
  conexao.Next;
  end;
```

Nessa linha `if (conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02' and conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04') then` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean'

Porque?

Comment: `conexao` é de qual classe?

Comment: é uma table, lista os campos de uma tabela. vou ampliar o código

Comment: então, sei que é uma table, quero saber qual ela é, se é uma dbx, firedac etc...

Comment: oi @JúniorMoreira, consegui resolver. Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é apenas separar as comparações usando parênteses:

`if ((conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02') and (conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04')) then`

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente `FieldValues['NOME_FIELD']` resulta é um `Variant`, sem um typecast adequado pode resultar em erros exatamente igual a este apresentado.

O correto é você informar o nome e tipo do field, segue exemplo.

```
NOME_TABELA.FieldByName('NOME_FIELD').AsString = '02'
NOME_TABELA.FieldByName('NOME_FIELD').AsInteger = 02
NOME_TABELA.FieldByName('NOME_FIELD').AsBoolean = True
```

E por ai vai.